# Selecting the right candidates for spring bean. What to what not to

Tags: spring, spring-bean

Last year when I started learning spring I remember an article that expalined that not all pojos are to be defined as beans. So I'm planning to create a web app say EmployeeMaintenance. CRUD Functionalities are there. I will surely end up creating pojos like Employee , EmployeeSupplementaryDetails, Address etc. Should I makes these beans and configure them in xml or annotate whatever. I'm sure my understanding of bean is not enough. I know that Dbconn , services etc should definitely be declared as bean.

All I need is what are the parameters I should consider before I make a pojo a Spring Bean.

Answer (score 1):

General rule for making Java class a Spring bean is to ask yourself if you need to inject object into some other object or if you want the object to be managed by Spring components. The classes you listed as example doesn't seem to be good candidates for being Spring beans - they represent model data and will be passed as some service's methods parameters.
Examples of typical CRUD application beans:

- `EmployeeService` (you would want to inject it to controller or other service)
- `EmployeeRepository` / `EmployeeDao`
- `EmployeeController` (it will be bean managed by Spring's MVC framework)
- etc.

Spring beans are building blocks of your application. Let's suppose you need to create web application for storing and managing employees records (creating, retrieving, updating, deleting). What you will need is web controller that will handle incoming requests for several operations (`EmployeeController`). Good practice is that controller doesn't implement any business logic - all it should do is to delegate work to service beans. So you would need bean like `EmployeeService`. Then controller would ask service to do some work (give me employees list / remove John Smith from database / change salary for Ann Jackson / etc). So service will be controller's dependency (**service is injected into controller**). Service can also have some dependencies (like repository object, which is responsible for handling communication with data storage) and these dependencies would be injected to service. Dependency management is Spring's core feature.

Good practice in object oriented programming is to have small classes that are responsible for doing one kind of actions. Such objects are much easier to test and understand. The more classes you have, the building application from blocks is harder, so it's worth to delegate it to framework like Spring. Without Spring you would need to create controller class, then inside of it create service, then inside of it create other dependencies and so on. Spring does it for you, so all you need to do is to declare dependencies and they will be injected automatically. If you want to replace implementation of your service with another (for example repository that used XML file for storing data with repository storing data in relational database) then you just have to change your bean definition.

Regarding to beans managed by Spring, typical example is database transaction manager (eg. `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager`). If you define such bean, and declare which methods should be transactional, then Spring will take care of transactions management (will open, commit or rollback transactions automatically).

Comment: Thanks this is the Kind of the answer I expected. When you need to inject one object to another. Or to be managed by spring component. Can you give an example real time scenario ? Just trying to understand  from your perspective